# update number in javascript on input change

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number in javascript that I need to update when an input is changed.

I want 'amount: 20000' to reflect what has been entered into the #customValue input multiplied by 100.

So if a user entered '30' in the input, 'amount: 20000' would be updated to 'amount: 3000'

Any ideas how I would accomplish this would be greatly appreciated! : )

```
<input id="customValue" value="200" />

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  handler.open({
    amount: 20000
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `input` is a self closing tag like `img`, so the `200</input>` bit of your HTML is useless. And what you're asking is still **vague**.

Comment: What kind of input field has a value 20000 and 200 between the tags. How did u introduce a </input>

Comment: to add an additional 00 to the value you can either multiply by 100 if its a number or use `value + "00"` if its a string. and use `onchange` to track the change in value

Comment: @Craicerjack multiplying it by a 100 or adding `"00"` won't care if it's a number or a string because `"7" * 100 === 700` and `7 + "00" === "700"`. So either one will do. The problem is whether the value is `NaN` or not.

Comment: Ah yes you're right sorry @ibrahim mahrir, I've fixed that input html and tried to explain my question further, I hope it helps.

Comment: @TimDonaldson `handler` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your `handler` variable is undefined. In the example below, I'm adding an EventListener to the Purchase button. When a user clicks on this button, it will take the value of the input field and multiply it by 100.

You should validate whether the entered value is a valid integer.

```js
document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var customValue = document.getElementById('customValue').value;
    
    // validate to check if customValue is a valid integer
    
    console.log(parseInt(customValue) * 100); // log new amount to console
});
```

```html
<input id="customValue" value="200" />

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var value = document.getElementById("customValue").value * 100; // multiply the customValue by a 100 and assign it to the variable value

    // use value whereever you like:
    alert(value);
});
```

```html
<input id="customValue" value="200" />

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
```

Comment: That changes the value of the input fields itself, so clicking on purchase multiple times changes the initial value entered by the user